# SDL Benchmark Sound

Tags: c++, audio, sdl, benchmarking

I am doing a benchmark project between two graphical libraries (SDL, SFML) for my final cs project. I got it almost finished, however when I benchmark the speed of playing sounds, it always returns time taken 0, no matter how many loops he does. Do you know whats wrong with my code? The sound actually plays, however I should probably do some other algorithm.

```
void playSound()
{
    Mix_PlayChannel(-1, sound, 0);
}

void soundBenchmark(int numOfCycles)
{
    int time = SDL_GetTicks(), timeRequired;
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfCycles; i++) playSound();
    timeRequired = SDL_GetTicks() - time;
    cout << "Time required for " << numOfCycles << " cycles: " <<  timeRequired << " seconds.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `Mix_PlayChannel()` does not block the execution of the code. The function just send the data to the sound card( or equivalent) and returns.

You are going to have to remember the channel you used with `Mix_PlayChannel()` and then check periodically with `Mix_Playing()` whether that channel is playing or not and look at the time.